# finding f'(x) of a parametric integral function without evaluating it

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

> $$f(x)=\int_0^x \sqrt{1-sin(\pi t)} dt $$
>   Find $f'(x)$ without doing the integral.

I tried using the fundamental law of calculus with the inner function as $g(t)$
and evaluated it to $f'(x)= \frac d{dx} (G(x)-G(0))$ but I don't think I can do that without first evaluating the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

If
$$f(x) = \int_0^x g(t)\, dt$$
Then

$$f'(x)=g(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using the fundamental law of calculus with the inner function as $g(t)$
>   and evaluated it to $f'(x)= \frac d{dx} (G(x)-G(0))$ but I don't think I can do that without first evaluating the integral.

What is $G(x)$?  I presume you mean, an antiderivative of $g(x)$.  If $G$ is an antiderivative of $g$, what would $\frac{d}{dx}G(x)$ be?